# The Money Confetti

Tags: lateral-thinking

A box containing one hundred $\$100$ bills was emptied by tossing its contents out a window.  All of the money, which was real, fell onto the ground floor below.

After all of the bills landed, they were counted. $47$ bills had the Benjamin Franklin side facing down, while there were $43$ bills with the other side facing down.

How did this happen?

Comment: I tried editing it to make it a little more readable, but I might have unintentionally changed some of the wordplay (sorry). @TSLF you might want to give it a read :)

Comment: @hugh . Yes a good edit thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple really.

> Just make a money roll, or fold some of them to make them stand on edge. [image]!

My bills normally look like this:

> These will frequently land on edge. [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if

> 10 of the 100 bills are not the [standard US \$100 bills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_one-hundred-dollar_bill#/media/File:Obverse_of_the_series_2009_$100_Federal_Reserve_Note.jpg). They could be Canadian or Australian dollars, or older US versions (if they exist) with a different design.